# Saving data from Spark to Cassandra results in java.lang.ClassCastException

Tags: scala, apache-spark, cassandra, spark-cassandra-connector

I'm trying to save data from Spark to Cassandra in Scala using `saveToCassandra` for an RDD or save with a dataframe (both result in the same error).  The full message is:

> java.lang.ClassCastException:
>   com.datastax.driver.core.DefaultResultSetFuture cannot be cast to
>   com.google.common.util.concurrent.ListenableFuture

I've followed along with the code [here](https://github.com/datastax/spark-cassandra-connector/blob/master/doc/0_quick_start.md) and still seem to get the error.

I'm using Cassandra 3.6, Spark 1.6.1, and spark-cassandra-connector 1.6.  Let me know if there's anything else I can provide to help with the debugging.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had similar exception and fixed it after changing in build.sbt scala version:

```
scalaVersion := "2.10.6"
```

and library dependencies:

```
libraryDependencies ++= Seq(
  "com.datastax.spark" %% "spark-cassandra-connector" % "1.6.0",
  "com.datastax.cassandra" % "cassandra-driver-core" % "3.0.2",
  "org.apache.spark" %% "spark-core" % "1.6.1" % "provided",
  "org.apache.spark" %% "spark-sql" % "1.6.1" % "provided"
)
```

With this configuration example from [5-minute quick start guide](https://github.com/datastax/spark-cassandra-connector/blob/master/doc/0_quick_start.md) works fine.

Comment: Thanks, this helped fix the issue.  One of the main problems I was having is conflicting guava versions so if anyone comes across this error in the future I would look into that.  I wasn't able to solve it without putting the code into different projects, but I imagine there's a way without doing this (shading perhaps?  I don't know enough about it...).

Comment: @grzesiekw I too had the same problem. your library informations saved me. thanks

Comment: connector 1.6.0 depends on C* driver 3.0.0 if you check the branch source. I wonder why C* driver 3.0.2 is explicitly needed here. Also it's an interesting decision for Datastax to make breaking changes from 3.0.0 to 3.0.2.